# How can I hide nav bar when on top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me out with a small responsive web project I'm currently doing?

I want to hide the menu nav bar when the user is on the top most part of the page, and only show it when the user starts scrolling down (on the mobile version), but have no idea how to, below are my code segments (mostly based on W3school template as I'm trying to learn web page making and it is the most reliable source I've found so far):

```html
 <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="w3-top">
        <ul class="w3-navbar w3-sea-green w3-card-2 w3-left-align">
          <li class="w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-opennav w3-right">
            <a class="w3-padding-large" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-none w3-hover-text-sea-green-grey w3-padding-large">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="w3-hide-small"><a href="#download" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-text-sea-green-invert">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
          <li class="w3-hide-small"><a href="#about" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-text-sea-green-invert">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li class="w3-hide-small"><a href="#contact" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-text-sea-green-invert">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
        <div id="navDemo" class="w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-top" style="margin-top:46px">
          <ul class="w3-navbar w3-left-align w3-sea-green">
            <li><a class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-text-sea-green-invert" href="#download">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
            <li><a class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-text-sea-green-invert" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-text-sea-green-invert" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            // Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
                if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
                    x.className += " w3-show";
                } else { 
                    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
                }
            }

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            var modal = document.getElementById('ticketModal');
            window.onclick = function(event) {
              if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
        </script>
        
        <!--Header image-->
        <div class="mySlides w3-display-container w3-center">
            <img src="pics/header_img.png" style="width:100%; pointer-events:none;" draggable="false">
        </div>
```

Am really appreciating any help, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Always use:

```
.classList.add()    // To add the class
.classList.remove() // To remove the class
```

This makes your code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.classList.add("w3-show");
    } else { 
        x.classList.remove("w3-show");
    }
}
```

And finally, please don't follow W3Schools and you end up like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function change(){
navbar=document.getElementsByClassName("w3-top")[0];
if(window.scrollTop>20){
//show
navbar.style.display="block";
}else{
//hide
navbar.style.display="none";
}}
window.onload=window.onscroll=change;
```

On page load or if the user scroll, check if the user scrolled down...

Answer (score 0):

you have to detect when the user scroll or not and if not scroll add class hidden and if scroll remove class hidden.

```
$(window).scroll(function (){
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >=20) {
                $('.w3-top').removeClass('hidden');

            }
            else {
                $('.w3-top').addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
```

the css

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```